# Grafana Annotation Query against AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to fetch annotations from AWS Cloudwatch?

I can construct the annotation query against Cloudwatch datasource under **Dashboard -> Settings ->  Annotations**. But the query is not working and the annotations are showing up in the panels even though there are data available for the selected time period

Comment: I am also encountering this issue. "No events found" when attempting to set up a custom annotation query against ANY cloudwatch metric